# CentOS phpmyadmin folder forbidden

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server, mysql, phpmyadmin

installed php5,apache2,LAMP, PHPMyAdmin
but if I type my IP and PHPMyAdmin like this **http://__my_IP__/phpmyadmin** it is showing the error

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /PHPMyAdmin/ on this server.

I edited **/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf** this file also added my IP address and allow to my IP address, still it is showing above error,

my phpmyadmin.conf file is like this now

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
#
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
# Apache 2.4
<RequireAny>
Require ip 27.34.248.3
#Require ip ::1
</RequireAny>
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
# Apache 2.2
Order Deny,Allow
```

how can I access PHPMyAdmin folder, so that I can manage database easily,
I'm using Redhat Linux 7.3, all packages are updated!

please help me!

Comment: Which user is running apache? Does the user have access rights to `/usr/share/phpMyadmin`?

Answer (score 1):

This works. Centos 7.

```
    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from All
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
  <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
     AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   # Apache 2.4
   <RequireAny>
   Require ip 127.0.0.1
   Require ip ::1
   Require ip 27.34.248.3
   </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   # Apache 2.2
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from All
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   Allow from ::1
   Allow from 27.34.248.3
  </IfModule>
  </Directory>
```

Restart the Apache service:

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

Comment: no sir, same error! I tried this also

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in apache config file of phpmyadmin

location is /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf

Default Config is:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Change it to:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Allow from All
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

and restart apache using command

```
# service httpd restart
```

OR

```
# systemctl restart  httpd.service
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52974/discussion-on-answer-by-pankaj-jackson-centos-phpmyadmin-folder-forbidden).